# Two ultrafilters converging to different points

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, filters

Suppose $U_1$ and $U_2$  be two different ultrafilters on $\mathbb Z$. Is it always possible to find a $f:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb C$ in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Z)$ such that $\lim_{U_1}f\neq \lim_{U_2}f$ ?

If the ultrafilers happens to be principal then one can easily find such a $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, if one of them is principal then clearly there exists such an $f$.

More generally, assume $A\in U_1\setminus U_2$. Then in particular the complement of $A$, $A^c \in U_2$. Then we may define $f$ to be $1$ on $A$, $-1$ on $A^c$. It is clearly bounded and $\lim_{U_1}f = 1, \lim_{U_2}f = -1$